# Why renamed schema alter result of query pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have large parquet dataframe with invalid characters in the names of fields (dots and braces)
If I read it as is and print some aggregation

```py
>>> df1 = spark.read.parquet(source)
>>> df1.select('`A.B.C`').fillna(0).agg({'`A.B.C`' : 'max'}).show()
+----------+
|max(A.B.C)|
+----------+
|  5989.625|
+----------+
```

I want to rename the columns for convenient further work. If I do it via schema

```py
schema = df1.schema
new_fields = [
    StructField(f.name.replace('.', '___').replace('(', '-').replace(')', '-'), f.dataType, f.nullable) for f in schema.fields
]
new_schema = StructType(new_fields)

df2 = spark.read.schema(new_schema).parquet(source)
```

Then aggregation gives another result

```py
>>> df2.select('A__B__C').fillna(0).agg({'A__B__C' : 'max'}).show()
+------------+
|max(A__B__C)|
+------------+
|         0.0|
+------------+
```

If I do renaming via mapping

```py
mapping = {c : c.replace('.', '___').replace('(', '-').replace(')', '-') for c in df1.columns}
df3 = df1.select([F.col(f'`{c}`').alias(mapping[c] for c in df1.columns])
```

it works with aggregation

```py
>>> df3.select('A__B__C').fillna(0).agg({'A__B__C' : 'max'}).show()
+------------+
|max(A__B__C)|
+------------+
|    5989.625|
+------------+
```

However when I try to save it for testing

```py
df3.sample(fraction=0.0001).write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('test_table')
```

It gives error

`Attribute name "Some.Col(1)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t="`

despite `"Some.Col(1)" in df3.columns`  gives `False` and `"Some__Col-1-" in df3.columns` gives `True` and so does direct indexing.

Meanwhile, using `withColumnRenamed` for every column takes much longer time so I didn't test it.

So why does using the new schema alter output of aggregation? Why does renaming work with aggregation but fail at writing, as if some columns were not renamed? How can I do proper renaming?

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```py
df2 = df1.selectExpr('`A.B.C` A__B__C')
```

to rename the column at time of selection and:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
df2.agg(sf.max(df1.A__B__C).alias('max_A__B__C'))
```

to rename the max (or another selectExpr/select with alias) so there are no "()" stopping the save

Comment: I do not save aggregation, I save fraction of initial dataframe. Also it does not explain why there is unrenamed column during save when it should not be there.